# React jsx array component does not re-render when state changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made a jsx array react component. This component should change according to the state value, but react does not re-render even when state change and the jsx array changes.

If I display the state using console.log, the state changes and the items (jsx array component) values ​​change, but no re-render occurs.

```
const Teams = () => {
    const [teams, setTeams] = useState([
    {
        id: "sldkfjsdf",
        level: 0,
        name: "test1",
        children: [{ id: "kjhckjhs", level: 1, name: "test1-1", children: [] }]
     },
     { children: [], id: "sdlkfjsdf234", level: 0, name: "test2" }
    ]);

    var items = [];

    const deleteNode = id => {
        const tmpNodes = teams;

        // check level 0
        var index = tmpNodes.findIndex(tmpNode => tmpNode.id === id);
        if (index >= 0) {
            tmpNodes.splice(index, 1);
        } else {
            // check level 1
            tmpNodes.forEach(tmpTeam => {
            index = tmpTeam.children.findIndex(child => child.id === id);
            if (index >= 0) {
                tmpTeam.children.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
      }

      setTeams(tmpNodes);
    };

    if (teams) {
    teams.forEach(team => {
      items.push(
        <div
          onClick={() => {
            deleteNode(team.id);
          }}
          key={team.id}
        >
          {team.name}
        </div>
      );
      team.children.forEach(child => {
        items.push(
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              deleteNode(team.id);
            }}
            key={child.id}
          >
            {child.name}
          </div>
        );
      });
    });
  }
  return <>{items}</>;
};

export default Teams;
```

I expect when I delete node, react re-render "items".

Comment: Does it re-render if you add a 'key' property to each item with the node id as the value? For dynamically populated arrays of content react doesn't have a way of telling two such values apart without the key property. If you look at the developer tools, you'll probably see there are warnings.

Comment: can you include the full source code for your component?

Comment: How does your `deleteNode` looks like? This looks like it's an important part that might be causing these issues

Comment: I uploaded all the codes. please let me know the solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mutating `teams` inside `deleteNode`.

Even though you are assigning `teams` to `tempNodes`, this is still the same object reference.

You can quickly fix this by creating a copy of `teams` and assigning it to `tempNodes` using the spread operator `...`

All you need to do is changing

```
const tmpNodes = teams;
```

To

```
// Create a copy of teams as a new array
const tmpNodes = [...teams];
```

Comment: The way you told me was right.  After I changed the code, it worked. I saved you a lot of time and effort. thank you very much.

Comment: sorry mistake.. you save me... ^^